# file_get_contents HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 501 Method Not Implemented

Tags: php

I am trying to grab some information from a json ecoded page, however I'm receiving the HTTP/1.1 501 Method Not Implemented error while assigning the value to the variable $data

```
   if(isset($_GET['xblaccount'])) {
        $gamertag = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['xblaccount']));
        $url = 'http://www.xboxleaders.com/api/profile.json?gamertag=' . urlencode($gamertag);
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
   }
```

I've also tried

```
   $gamertag = 'kfj32j8fj23f';
```

And receive the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question because the code **does work** if you use an actual account name (e.g. `Stallionh83` or `Major Nelson`).

Having discovered this I then checked the headers in a browser (FF) which also returned the 501 response header. I assume therefore that this is then a server side response for non-accounts.

Bearing that in mind I suggest editing your code to:

```
if(isset($_GET['xblaccount'])) {
    $gamertag = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['xblaccount']));
    $url = 'http://www.xboxleaders.com/api/profile.json?gamertag=' . urlencode($gamertag);
    $data = @file_get_contents($url); // @ to suppress the warning
    if($data){
        //Account exists...
    }
    else{
        //Account doesn't exist...
    }
}
```

`$data` will return `FALSE` if the account doesn't exist, otherwise it will return the `JSON` string.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't realize it would return 501 in the headers if the account wasn't found.

Comment: No problem, it seems like an odd behaviour for them to implement - certainly wasn't my first thought! @Sheikh thank you :)